# 2 lines of text in xaml button on wp 8 xaml/C# app

Tags: xaml, button, windows-phone-8, newline

```
<Button x:Name="play_tues"  Content="Psalm 82   פרק פב    " 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,108,-104,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="124" Width="254" />
```

I have tried

```
\n     \r\n    &    <NewLine/>.   //these seem to be for WPF not WP8
```

I want Psalm 82 on line1 and פרק פב on line2 of my button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with multiple `TextBlock`s as `Button` content :

```
<Button x:Name="play_tues"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,108,-104,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="124" Width="254">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Psalm 82</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>פרק פב</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Could use line feed characters `&#10;` / `&#xa;` if you wanted to do it inline like; `<Button x:Name="play_tues"  Content="Psalm 82&#10; פרק פב"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Its also useful. try this use Run inside TextBlock

```
<Button x:Name="play_tues" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,108,-104,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="124" Width="254"> 
 <TextBlock>
 <TextBlock.Inlines>
  <Run Text="פרק פב"/>
   Run Text="Psalm 82"/>
  </TextBlock.Inlines>
  </TextBlock>
</Button>
```